# Unexpected EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to swift and iOS! I have looked all around for different ways to pass an arrary[indexPath.row] to another view after a cell is selected. For some reason, mine is not working and I come up with the above error. I am trying to change the label on my other view controller to match the selected row which matches an array that is the label on the custom table view cell. For example, tableData[0] will be a label's text on the first row. I also deleted my other elements from the following code in this post to focus on the segue issue.  Here is my viewcontroller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


var tableData: [String] = ["8:00 am", "8:10 am", "8:20 am", "8:30 am", "8:40 am", "8:50 am", "9:00 am", "9:10 am", "9:20 am", "9:30 am", "9:40 am", "9:50 am", "10:00 am", "10:10 am", "10:20 am", "10:30 am", "10:40 am", "10:50 am", "11:00 am", "11:10 am", "11:20 am", "11:30 am", "11:40 am", "11:50 am", "12:00 pm", "12:10 pm", "12:20 pm", "12:30 pm", "12:40 pm", "12:50 pm", "1:00 pm", "1:10 pm", "1:20 pm", "1:30 pm", "1:40 pm", "1:50 pm", "2:00 pm", "2:10 pm", "2:20 pm", "2:30 pm", "2:40 pm", "2:50 pm", "3:00 pm", "3:10 pm", "3:20 pm", "3:30 pm", "3:40 pm", "3:50 pm", "4:00 pm", "4:10 pm", "4:20 pm", "4:30 pm", "4:40 pm", "4:50 pm", "5:00 pm"]


let conSegueIdentifier = "ShowConSegue"
var timeToPass:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    coursePicker.hidden = true;
    self.courseTextfield.delegate = self

    playerPicker.hidden = true;
    self.playerTextfield.delegate = self

    timePicker.hidden = true;
    self.timeTextfield.delegate = self

    datePicker.hidden = true;
    self.dateTextfield.delegate = self
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//tableview

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var numRows = tableData.count
    if(timeTextfield.text == timeData[1]) {
        numRows = 25
    }
    else if(timeTextfield.text == timeData[2]) {
        numRows = 30
    }
    return numRows
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TblCell

    if(timeTextfield.text == timeData[2]) {
        cell.lblTime.text = tableData[indexPath.row + 25]
        cell.lblOne.text = lblOneData[indexPath.row + 25]
    }
    else {
        cell.lblTime.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblOne.text = lblOneData[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.lblTwo.text = "Available"
    cell.lblThree.text = "Available"
    cell.lblFour.text = "Available"

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row

    performSegueWithIdentifier(conSegueIdentifier, sender: self)
    print(tableData[row])
}

//end of tableview

//segue
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == conSegueIdentifier {
        let cvc = segue.destinationViewController as! ConViewController;
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let valueToPass = tableData[indexPath.row]
        cvc.conName = courseTextfield.text
        cvc.conDateName = dateTextfield.text
        cvc.conTimeName = valueToPass
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you pinpoint the crash point? Are you actually getting to the prepareForSegue? put a breakpoint in its first line and see if you get there. After that it's a question of stepping over and stepping into.

Comment: In your performSegueWithIdentifier, try passing indexPath itself in place of self in sender and in prepareForSegue method AnyObject will be the indexPath. Try passing this value now.

Comment: @RoyFalk the crash point is at the line "let indexPath : NSIndexPath..." The app builds and everything works correctly until I select a cell, then it crashes and gives the error and that line.

Comment: @BhavukJain I tried that and I still receive the same error at the line "let indexPath: NSIndex Path..."

Comment: @SwaggyMcMuffins You don't need that line now. You already have the indexPath. Comment that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice what you did:
In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you got the selected row and deselected the row.
You then called prepareForSegue and asked the tableView for the selected row, but now, there isn't one. The function returns a nil
If you remove the 'deselectRowAtIndexPath' it should work.

More to the point, you should read the section on Optionals in the [swift tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309). You are appending an exclamation mark to self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow. That means it is potentially a nil value and you are absolutely certain it is not.

To quote Apple:

> "Once you’re sure that the optional does contain a value, you can access its underlying value by adding an exclamation mark (!) to the end of the optional’s name. The exclamation mark effectively says, “I know that this optional definitely has a value; please use it.” This is known as forced unwrapping of the optional’s value"